# Deploy .net core 2.2 Web Api to IIS 10..Issue?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I have a Angular front end and >net core 2.2 api at back! Everything is working fine in local. I published the angular app(front) to iis ..its working fine. Now I am tring to deploy the web Api to the iis. I am getting 404 issue. I have downloaded dot net core hosting bundle as well and set the Application Pool to "No Managed Code". But its not working at all. I cant pinpoint the issue as well? Can some one help me out please

I have tried adding a new website, and also  adding a application in default website. Not of it is working

This is my launchSetting.json  file.

Comment: Run a report and attach here to reveal how you configure IIS, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html You might also need to run failed request tracing to see where the 404 errors come from, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. 
It was because the app could not connect to local database(windows authentication) after it had been deployed to iis.After I made a user , and changed the connection string things worked out fine.